# NestJS can't resolve dependencies of class that is provided with a factory

Tags: nestjs

Let me introduce you the `AlgoModule`:

```
const apiFactory = {
    provide: 'API',
    useFactory: (moduleRef: ModuleRef, config: ConfigService) => {
        const apiService: Type<IApi> = config.getApiService();
        return moduleRef.get(apiService)
    },
    inject: [ModuleRef, ConfigService]
}

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    providers: [


        // Services
        ApiService,
        ApiTestService,
        TestService,

        // Factories
        apiFactory 
    ],
    exports: []
})
export class AlgoModule {}
```

This module imports the `ConfigModule` and has a factory that creates an `IApi` instance which is either `ApiService` or `ApiTestService` based on env parameters that `ConfigService` under `ConfigModule` has loaded.

The factory uses the `ConfigService` injected onto it and the `ModuleRef` in order to create an instance of `IApi`.

This is an example of one of the implementations of IApi - `ApiService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService implements IApi {
    constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
    }
}
```

Now when I create a new service and put it in the provides of AlgoModule, let's say `TestService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor(
        private config: ConfigService,
        @Inject('API') private api: IApi) {
    }
}
```

What I did here is, inject IApi with the token 'API' which is what I set up in `AlgoModule` using the `apiFactory`

I will get the following error upon start:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ApiService(?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AlgoModule context.
```

What did I do wrong?

I am wondering, because I imported the ConfigModule within `AlgoModule` so the factory should automatically have the dependencies of it.

ConfigService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

    serviceMapping = {
        prod: ApiService,
        test: ApiTestService
    };

    getEnv(): string | 'prod' | 'test' {
        return String(process.env.ENV);
    }

    getApiService(): Type<IApi> {
        const env = this.getEnv();
        return this.serviceMapping[env];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sourcecode of the ConfigService please?

Comment: @csakbalint Provided ConfigService

Comment: I recreated your project with a minimal example, and it ran without issues. Maybe this issue is not related to this code, but somewhere else, where you accidently tries to instantiate the ApiService. Here you can find my test: https://gist.github.com/csakbalint/cddb36ac87fccd723e7ba72f040b35da
Tell me, if you found something!

Comment: @csakbalint I found out the issue. It's because I have the serviceMapping that includes in the Type values of these classes (see the config class I added) which triggers the injection while it has nothing to inject of these types (ConfigService). But why would it? it's just a type? I would love an answer on this!

Comment: No it isn't. I think this issue exists outside of this code you provided, otherwise it would show up in my example. Somewhere, where you try to use the ApiService, but wouldn't import the ConfigService.

Answer (score -1):

Did you call ConfigModule.forRoot with flag isGlobal somewhere in global modules?

If not then you must because ConfigModule does not work as you imagine.

ConfigModule.forRoot or forFeature exposes ConfigService token for module but plain ConfigModule do not unless it is global.

Comment: ConfigModule is a module I created, I don't have forRoot for it